# The portal is having issues getting authentication tokens for Microsoft_Azure_Storage

Tags: azure-storage, azure-powershell, azureportal

I'm having trouble accessing an Azure Storage Blob Container using the Azure Portal. I can see the Storage Account blade OK, and the Container I want to use is listed, but when I try opening the Container blade I get the following message:

> The portal is having issues getting authentication tokens for
>   Microsoft_Azure_Storage

I've been getting this message for several days now. It first happened when I was trying to import an Azure SQL Database from the Storage Account - I'd just exported the SQL Database from a different server in the same subscription, and the export worked fine.

Since then I've tried creating a new Storage Account, and it behaves the same way - the account is created, and I can add a Blob Container, but I can't access the blade for the Container - I get the same message. I've tried setting the Access Policy to Blob or Container, but this makes no difference.

If I use PowerShell (logged in as the same user) then the following commands work fine, and I can see the blob exported from the database:

```coffee
$storageAccount = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName xxx -Name xxx
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container xxx -Context $storageAccount.Context
```

Is there anything I can change in the Portal to fix this?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

We cannot reproduce this issue and it may be due to your account / environment.

Please create an `Azure support request` following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request), and the azure support engineer can help with it.